# Cannot lock an unsaved transient instance

Tags: java

I'm struggling with a problem in my Java EE project. I can not figure out what my mistake is. If someone could help me, I'd very thankful.

This is the problem:

```
    Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: cannot lock an unsaved transient instance: com.carveras.escola.model.Alumne
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLockEventListener.onLock(DefaultLockEventListener.java:74)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLock(SessionImpl.java:751)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLock(SessionImpl.java:744)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1200(SessionImpl.java:204)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$LockRequestImpl.lock(SessionImpl.java:2682)
at com.carver_as.carverjsf.model.CarverPureHibernate5DAO.reattach(CarverPureHibernate5DAO.java:438)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:206)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.reattach(Unknown Source)
at com.carveras.escola.web.EditaPersonaBean.init(EditaPersonaBean.java:55)
... 82 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Exception message says clearly, you cannot lock a object which is not yet present in database(such object is called Transient). The `lock()` call will lock the row in the database. You're trying to lock a transient object, meaning that Hibernate doesn't even know if the object has a corresponding row in the database or not.

Answer (score 0):

From [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview)

> Transient - an object is transient if **it has just been instantiated
>   using the new operator, and it is not associated with a Hibernate
>   Session**. It has no persistent representation in the database and no
>   identifier value has been assigned. Transient instances will be
>   destroyed by the garbage collector if the application does not hold a
>   reference anymore. Use the Hibernate Session to make an object
>   persistent (and let Hibernate take care of the SQL statements that
>   need to be executed for this transition).

Meaning you need to do something like

```
Long id = (Long) session.save(myObject);
```

so that hibernate knows about that object (is associated with the Hibernate session) and saved in database